# Filter view by JSON object's parameter value in Apache CouchDB

Tags: apache, view, nosql, couchdb, cloudant

For an Apache CouchDB instance, there is an existing view defined - viewPrincipals. The response that I get via URI(*X_db/_design/XDoc/_view/viewAllPrincipals*) is:

```
{
   "total_rows":2,
   "offset":0,
   "rows":[
      {
         "id":"##SP:hosttest1.ite1.com@ITE1.IDNG.COM",
         "key":"##SP:hosttest1.ite1.com@ITE1.IDNG.COM",
         "value":"2-80da25dcdcb8bae15019929bfd577893"
      },
      {
         "id":"##SP:hosttest200.ite1100.com@ITE1100.IDNG.COM",
         "key":"##SP:hosttest200.ite1100.com@ITE1100.IDNG.COM",
         "value":"2-80da25dcdcb8bae15019929bfd577893"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I need to filter this JSON response via URI query so that I get only the JSON object with *id* **starting** with "*##SP:hosttest1.ite1.com*"
Is this possible to acheive in CouchDB via URI parameters for filtering ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
GET /X_db/_design/XDoc/_view/viewAllPrincipals??startkey="##SP:hosttest1.ite1.com"&endkey="##SP:hosttest1.ite1.com\uffff"
```

You can take a look at [relevant section of the documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/views/collation.html#string-ranges).

---

EXPLANATION:

I have a view named `title` which is indexing/sorting my docs according to the `key` (defined in my view map function) like this:

```
$ curl -k -X GET https://admin:****@192.168.1.106:6984/sample/_design/title/_view/title
{"total_rows":19,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"doc8","key":"Adam","value":["אדאם יהוה"]},
{"id":"doc14","key":"Average Joe","value":[null]},
{"id":"doc2","key":"between","value":["בין"]},
{"id":"doc12","key":"Cool","value":[null]},
{"id":"doc7","key":"David Salomon","value":["דיויד שלמן"]},
{"id":"doc1","key":"Earth","value":["ארץ"]},
{"id":"doc13","key":"Geek","value":[null]},
{"id":"doc0","key":"Hello elephant","value":["שלום פיל"]},
{"id":"doc5","key":"Jacob","value":["יעקב"]},
{"id":"doc6","key":"Jacob","value":["ישראל"]},
{"id":"doc4","key":"on you","value":["עליכם"]},
{"id":"doc11","key":"Pretty","value":[null]},
{"id":"doc10","key":"Sir","value":[null]},
{"id":"doc9","key":"Start","value":["ראש"]},
{"id":"doc3","key":"telmeg","value":["מגידו"]},
...
]}
```

Now, if I want to query `title` view to get only docs starting with letter `S`, I can add query parameters like below:

```
?startkey="S"&endkey="S\uffff"
```

Since `S` is the very first possible case and `\uffff` is the last Unicode possible, it covers all the cases of equivalent to `S*` in wild-card notation. Therefore, I can get all docs starting with `S` by running:

```
$ curl -k -X GET 'https://admin:****@192.168.1.106:6984/sample/_design/title/_view/title?startkey="S"&endkey="S\uffff"'
{"total_rows":19,"offset":12,"rows":[
{"id":"doc10","key":"Sir","value":[null]},
{"id":"doc9","key":"Start","value":["ראש"]}
]}
```

---

[The documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/views/collation.html#string-ranges) is using `\ufff0`, but I used `\uffff` and it works. I'm not quite sure about the difference. Maybe I'm missing something.